# Jquery get the RadioButton added attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have a problem which drives me crazy now. On my webpage I have a RadioButton and I add attribute to it like that :

> **in ...asp**

```
<div id="radio" class="C_Radio">
    <asp:RadioButton id="rad1" GroupName="typeSelect" runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton id="rad2" GroupName="typeSelect" runat="server" />
</div>
```

> **in ...asp.vb**

```
rad1.Attributes.Add("rad1", "10") 
rad2.Attributes.Add("rad2", "20")
```

> **in fireBug I see this:**

```
<div class="C_Radio" id="radio">
    <span rad1="10">
    <span rad2="20">
```

so the values are there but I can NOT get them back.

> **I tryed the following in JQuery**

```
var test;

test = $("#radio input:checked + label").text();    //label of radioButton
test = $("#radio input:checked").val();         //id of selected radioButton
test = $(test);                     //undefined
test = $(test).val();                   //undefined
test = $(test).attr();                  //undefined
test = $(test).attr("test");            //undefined
test = $(test).attr("value");           //id of selected radioButton
test = $("rad1").val();             //undefined
test = $("rad1").attr();                //undefined
test = $("#radio").attr("rad1");        //undefined
test = $("#radio input:checked").attr("rad1");      //undefined
test = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();      //undefined
test = $("input[name='rad1']:checked").val();       //undefined
```

Can anyone help me please? I could do it on other way I know, but I'd like to get solved this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case is solved like this:

```
test = $("#rad1").parent().attr("rad1");  //Result 10
test = $("#rad2").parent().attr("rad2");  //Result 20
```